# Computing and Processing millions of binary tree nodes in parallel

Tags: hadoop, data-structures, parallel-processing, binary-tree, bigdata

I am going to develop a referral management system which will be like binary tree. One node in the tree will refer only 2 nodes. Those 2 nodes will refer 4 (2 each) and 4 will refer 8 and so on.

With the time this tree will grow exponentially by 2 power n. Eg at 100th level of tree I can have max 2 power 100 nodes ie (1267650600228229401496703205376)

Each node will have lot of information with it.

I would like to implement functionalities like :

1. getAllChildNodes for any parent node
2. getParent for a child
3. getAllAncestors for a child
4. I should be able to add child to any parent who has less than 2 child

So, in parallel there can be millions of add/remove/traverse operations on the tree as multiple users at a time will be adding nodes below them

Can someone please suggest me what tool/technology/hardware should I use to process such a large amount of data?

Comment: *100th level of tree I can have max 2 power 100 nodes ie (1267650600228229401496703205376)*  I bet you can't.

Comment: To hold that much data, you'll need all of the disk drives ever manufactured. And then some.

Comment: Doesn't sound like they have invented it yet... hmmm.... are you assuming that the tree is perfectly balanced? It it isn't it maybe 100 nodes deep in one place but contain a lot less data than the theoretical maximum.

Comment: To keep access times to a minimum you would use balanced trees (b-tree). If stored to disk these are typically arranged as multiway trees where you pack x nodes together into a block which maps to a disk block.

Comment: @AnthonyLambert : Balanced tree is an ideal scenario, but I am sure it would not be balanced always. Yes, you are correct there may be some branches which can reach to 100 levels or even more but not all the branches.

Comment: Can BigData/hadoop help me in such a scenario?

Comment: No, BigData/hadoop can't help you. The volume of data is entirely too large. Even if you had enough storage space (which you don't), it'd still take way too long to store the data. If you could store 2^30 (a billion) items per second, it would still take 2^70 seconds (37 *trillion* years) just to store all the items.

Comment: I assume the 2^100 is just an example not an actual estimate? What would be your estimate? Also, why use a binary tree? Binary tree have a lot of storage overhead and long traversal routes (both due to the many nodes).

Comment: I have to use binary tree because every 2 nodes will be referred by 1 node, so relationship is binary. I do not think 2^30 transaction will happen in seconds. Only few thousands transaction may occur in parallel. Tree can go to any level and I am sure it will not be balanced.
Sequence is :

1) Add 1 node in the system
2) 1 node will refer and add 2 nodes in the system
3) 2 nodes will refer and add 4 nodes in the system
4) so on it will continue to 2^n in next levels

Its not necessary that it has to be balanced all the time. This node addition process can be parallel